# .NET Core 3.1 API fails when using DevOps CI/CD

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1, azure-appservice, visual-studio-publish

Deploying a .NET Core 3.1 API Application to an Azure WebApp fails when using DevOps CI/CD Release Pipeline but succeeds when Publishing from Visual Studio

### Create .NET Core 3.1 Api App

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Create Azure Web App

Create a new resource of type “Web App”

[image]

[image]

### Publish from Visual Studio

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ok, so that works, now here's what happens when trying to deploy using DevOps CI/CD Release Pipeline..

### Deploy via DevOps CI/CD

… create another Web App resource `junk-devops-cicd` ...

[image]

#### deploy via ci/cd pipeline

[image]

Create the Build Pipeline

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Create the Release Pipeline

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So it fails going through CI/CD pipeline. But not VS Publish Manager

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your .net core application build task is wrong. i guess solution is not getting build successfully . try visualstudio build  instead of netBuild 
[image]

And make sure your Artifact Build directory path been set correctly. root path should be **$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)**

Comment: can you go to your app service WWW folder using kudo tools and check what are the files being uploaded via release pipline?

Comment: yes they were, but the problem was that I needed to select visualstudio build vs dotnetcore build. and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If the first pipeline you created is a CI pipeline (Build pipeline) you need to select the "ASP .net" template not the "Azure web App". this pipeline will restore nuget,build and publish the artifact of your app in the artifact store of AzureDevops. Then your release pipeline will get this artifact and deploy it into Azure.

the "Azure web App" template is a CI/CD template.

I think the mistake you have mad is deleting some essentials steps for building a package, "Use Nuget" and "Nuget restore".

To build an artifact correctly you need to have those steps:
[Asp .net build pipline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81KHH.png)